# Why doesn't .NET CLI provide synthesized copy constructors and assignment operators for reference classes?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I am writing a simple GUI using Visual C++ in the .NET framework and I am curious why there are no synthesized copy constructors or assignment operators for reference classes?

Basically, I started a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio and have my own data structure of parameters. But, I need instances of it (and pointers to instances of it) in my MainForm class and since the latter is a reference class I had to make my struct reference too.

Comment: Because c++cli is a completely different language than c++, whose object sematics are closer to c# than c++. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx

Comment: Further more, "assignment operator" makes no sense with reference classes. All instaces of reference classes (such as Foo^) are actually handles, `Foo^ a = gcnew Foo(); Foo^ b = a;` means that b and a are the SAME HANDLE.

Comment: @IdeaHat, I appreciate the response but I realize they are different languages. I was hoping someone could give a brief explanation of the underlying motivation.

Comment: If you realize they are different languages, then why annoy everyone by willfully mis-tagging?

Comment: Dangerous question.  All classes in C++ are value classes, they have the copy ctor and assignment operator predefined because that's what a value class needs to copy properly.  The need for copying is greatly reduced in a language with a garbage collector.  Basic things like returning an object or storing an object in a collection doesn't require copying or reference counting to keep memory management manageable.

Comment: @Deduplicator, it was not willfully mnis-tagged, it was willfully tagged both c++ and c++cli because the implied root of the question is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the long and short of it is because C++CLI is a .NET language, which is a *reference* based language (garbage collected, but the two are indistinguishable in this case). Almost everything default to a reference, meaning that all instances are accessed via handles, so in

```
Foo^ a = gcnew Foo(); Foo^ b = a;
```

`a` and `b` point to the same object. This is also true for other reference-defualting languages like Java.

The side effect of this is, unlike C++, nobody "owns" the instance pointed to by `a`. The actual lifetime of a is simply longer than all the handles. This makes making a default copy constuctor impossible. Take the simple reference class:

```
ref class Foo
{
   Bar^ bar;
};
```

When we make the copy of Foo, the compiler has no way of knowing if Foo owns bar or not. Thus, it cannot decide whether or not to copy the handle (shallow copy) or instantiate a new `Bar` (deep copy). Thus, the designers of such language don't typically provide a default copy constructor.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't any different in C++, the default copy ctor blindly copies a pointer.

Comment: @HansPassant I get what you are trying to say, but the value-semantics of C++ means that the copy constructor of a pointer is copying the value of the pointer. This is a known issue with c++ (the ownership of values pointed to by raw-pointers are always weird), which is why we have the rule of 3, but modern thinking on the subject is to try and follow the "rule of 0": Use smart pointers so ownership is always explicit, and the default copy constructor always makes sense. But in garbage collected languages, because ownership is so nebulous, we can't make any claims either way.